# Java password generator

Tags: java, passwords, generator

I am trying to create a java program that creates a password, either all lowercase, lowercase and uppercase, lowercase and uppercase and numbers, lowercase and uppercase and numbers and punctuation and the program also has to create one of those password that the user picks and and has to generate a password length according to what the user picks. I have already generated the password options for the user to pick from and have prompted him to pick one. I am now stuck on how to create the password types that were mentioned above. One person suggested me to use ASCII values and then converting them to text. I know how to convert them to text, but it will display number, letters, and punctuations. Is there any way that I can just generate ASCII values for just lowercase letters? Also how will I generate a password according to the user's length that they give?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code. BTW, take a look at https://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/wiki/vtpassword

Answer (score 61):

I use this immutable class.
It uses the **builder pattern**.
*It doesn't support extension*.

```
public final class PasswordGenerator {

    private static final String LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String UPPER = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";
    private static final String PUNCTUATION = "!@#$%&*()_+-=[]|,./?><";
    private boolean useLower;
    private boolean useUpper;
    private boolean useDigits;
    private boolean usePunctuation;

    private PasswordGenerator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty constructor is not supported.");
    }

    private PasswordGenerator(PasswordGeneratorBuilder builder) {
        this.useLower = builder.useLower;
        this.useUpper = builder.useUpper;
        this.useDigits = builder.useDigits;
        this.usePunctuation = builder.usePunctuation;
    }

    public static class PasswordGeneratorBuilder {

        private boolean useLower;
        private boolean useUpper;
        private boolean useDigits;
        private boolean usePunctuation;

        public PasswordGeneratorBuilder() {
            this.useLower = false;
            this.useUpper = false;
            this.useDigits = false;
            this.usePunctuation = false;
        }

        /**
         * Set true in case you would like to include lower characters
         * (abc...xyz). Default false.
         *
         * @param useLower true in case you would like to include lower
         * characters (abc...xyz). Default false.
         * @return the builder for chaining.
         */
        public PasswordGeneratorBuilder useLower(boolean useLower) {
            this.useLower = useLower;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set true in case you would like to include upper characters
         * (ABC...XYZ). Default false.
         *
         * @param useUpper true in case you would like to include upper
         * characters (ABC...XYZ). Default false.
         * @return the builder for chaining.
         */
        public PasswordGeneratorBuilder useUpper(boolean useUpper) {
            this.useUpper = useUpper;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set true in case you would like to include digit characters (123..).
         * Default false.
         *
         * @param useDigits true in case you would like to include digit
         * characters (123..). Default false.
         * @return the builder for chaining.
         */
        public PasswordGeneratorBuilder useDigits(boolean useDigits) {
            this.useDigits = useDigits;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set true in case you would like to include punctuation characters
         * (!@#..). Default false.
         *
         * @param usePunctuation true in case you would like to include
         * punctuation characters (!@#..). Default false.
         * @return the builder for chaining.
         */
        public PasswordGeneratorBuilder usePunctuation(boolean usePunctuation) {
            this.usePunctuation = usePunctuation;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Get an object to use.
         *
         * @return the {@link gr.idrymavmela.business.lib.PasswordGenerator}
         * object.
         */
        public PasswordGenerator build() {
            return new PasswordGenerator(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will generate a password depending the use* properties you
     * define. It will use the categories with a probability. It is not sure
     * that all of the defined categories will be used.
     *
     * @param length the length of the password you would like to generate.
     * @return a password that uses the categories you define when constructing
     * the object with a probability.
     */
    public String generate(int length) {
        // Argument Validation.
        if (length <= 0) {
            return "";
        }

        // Variables.
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(length);
        Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());

        // Collect the categories to use.
        List<String> charCategories = new ArrayList<>(4);
        if (useLower) {
            charCategories.add(LOWER);
        }
        if (useUpper) {
            charCategories.add(UPPER);
        }
        if (useDigits) {
            charCategories.add(DIGITS);
        }
        if (usePunctuation) {
            charCategories.add(PUNCTUATION);
        }

        // Build the password.
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String charCategory = charCategories.get(random.nextInt(charCategories.size()));
            int position = random.nextInt(charCategory.length());
            password.append(charCategory.charAt(position));
        }
        return new String(password);
    }
}
```

This is a usage example,

```
PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new PasswordGenerator.PasswordGeneratorBuilder()
        .useDigits(true)
        .useLower(true)
        .useUpper(true)
        .build();
String password = passwordGenerator.generate(8); // output ex.: lrU12fmM 75iwI90o
```

Comment: this is really useful

Comment: It is really fast, too.

Comment: This is **NOT** guaranteed to generate a password that fully matches the "builder" settings. Eg.: even if you set `.useUpper(true)` the password may not contain ANY uppercase character.

Answer (score 20):

You can make use of `org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils` to generate random text/passwords. Please refer to [this](http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string/) link for example.

Answer (score 14):

Just in case it will be useful for somebody. The one line random password generator by standard Java 8 classes based on the ASCII range:

```
String password = new Random().ints(10, 33, 122).collect(StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
```

or

```
String password = new Random().ints(10, 33, 122).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)i)).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Here the length of password is 10. Of course you may set it randomly in some range as well.
And the characters are from the ASCII range 33-122 which are all special symbols, digits upper and lower cases.

If you need lower case letters only you just can set the range: 97-122

Comment: the last argument to `ints()` is exclusive so this won't include codepoint 122 (_z_) so should be 123 instead. If you're using special characters you might as well go up to 127 which includes _{_, _|_, _}_, and _~_.

Comment: I would change `new Random()` to `new SecureRandom()` and `.ints(10, 33, 122)` to a bit intuitive `.ints(10, '!', '{')`

Answer (score 10):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordHelper {        

    public static String generatePassword (int length) {

    //minimum length of 6
    if (length < 4) {
        length = 6;
    }

    final char[] lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
    final char[] uppercase = "ABCDEFGJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    final char[] numbers = "0123456789".toCharArray();
    final char[] symbols = "^$?!@#%&".toCharArray();
    final char[] allAllowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ0123456789^$?!@#%&".toCharArray();

    //Use cryptographically secure random number generator
    Random random = new SecureRandom();

    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < length-4; i++) {
        password.append(allAllowed[random.nextInt(allAllowed.length)]);
    }

    //Ensure password policy is met by inserting required random chars in random positions
    password.insert(random.nextInt(password.length()), lowercase[random.nextInt(lowercase.length)]);
    password.insert(random.nextInt(password.length()), uppercase[random.nextInt(uppercase.length)]);
    password.insert(random.nextInt(password.length()), numbers[random.nextInt(numbers.length)]);
    password.insert(random.nextInt(password.length()), symbols[random.nextInt(symbols.length)]);
    }

    return password.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; it's the only one that guarantees the password will contain the required combination of upper/lower/number/symbol.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
String lower = "abc...xyz";
String digits = "0123456789";
String punct = "!#$&...";
String  ...                      // further characer classes
```

(Note the `...` parts you must fill out yourself.)

From the options the user chooses, you create a string of characters to choose from by concatenating the corresponding character classes.

Finally you run a loop n times, where n is the number of characters wanted.
In each round, you pick a random character from the String you created and add it to the result:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int n = ....; // how many characters in password
String set = ....; // characters to choose from

for (i= 0; i < n; i++) {
    int k = ....;   // random number between 0 and set.length()-1 inklusive
    sb.append(set.charAt(k));
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as flexible but shorter version of [George Siggouroglou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891760/8121295).

## Generator class

```
public final class DefaultPasswordGenerator {
    private static final String[] charCategories = new String[] {
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
            "0123456789"
    };

    public static String generate(int length) {
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder(length);
        Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String charCategory = charCategories[random.nextInt(charCategories.length)];
            int position = random.nextInt(charCategory.length());
            password.append(charCategory.charAt(position));
        }

        return new String(password);
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
String passWord = PasswordGenerator.generate(10);
```

Answer (score 3):

### There is another Random String Generator

[George Siggouroglou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891760/13106495) created a very good answer. I have developed and changed his code with a more flexible.

### Features

1. It is used `SecureRandom` instead of `Random`. You can change with `Random` instead of it.
2. **Minimum characters count** added. Firstly, the algorithm chooses characters randomly by minimum characters. After minimum required characters are selected, it will be completed with rest characters in all available characters. Then all selected characters are swapped randomly.
3. You can use custom vocabulary with `custom` method.

#### Example Usage

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = new PasswordGenerator.Builder()
                .digits(4)
                .lower(1)
                .upper(2)
                .punctuation()
                .generate(10);

        System.out.println(password);

        // with custom
        password = new PasswordGenerator.Builder()
                .custom("1579", 1)
                .custom("Stackoverflow", 3)
                .lower()
                .generate(6);
        System.out.println(password);

    }
}
```

### Source Code

```java
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class PasswordGenerator {
    private final List<Rule> rules;

    private PasswordGenerator() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Empty constructor is not supported.");
    }

    private PasswordGenerator(Builder builder) {
        this.rules = builder.rules;
    }

    public String generate(int length) {
        if (length <= 0) {
            return "";
        }

        // shuffle rules
        List<Rule> shuffledRules = new ArrayList<>(rules);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledRules);

        // random instance, you can use `Random random = new Random();`
        Random random = new SecureRandom();

        // 1. STAGE - SELECT MINIMUM CHARACTERS FROM RULES THAT HAVE MINIMUM COUNT.
        List<Character> selectedChars = new ArrayList<>(selectCharactersByMinimumCount(random, shuffledRules));

        // 2. STAGE - SELECT MISSING LENGTH FROM ALL AVAILABLE CHARACTERS
        int missingLength = length - selectedChars.size();
        if (missingLength > 0) {
            selectedChars.addAll(selectCharactersByMissingLength(random, shuffledRules, missingLength));
        }

        // 3. STAGE - SHUFFLE SELECTED CHARS
        Collections.shuffle(selectedChars);

        // 4. STAGE - RETURN RESULT
        return selectedChars.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    /**
     * Select random characters from filter rules that they are defined minimum count value.
     *
     * @param random Random instance
     * @param rules  Rules
     * @return Randomly chosen characters
     */
    private List<Character> selectCharactersByMinimumCount(Random random, List<Rule> rules) {
        return rules.stream()
                .filter(rule -> rule.minimumCount > 0)
                .flatMap(rule ->
                        IntStream.range(0, rule.minimumCount)
                                .mapToObj(i -> rule.text.charAt(random.nextInt(rule.text.length()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Select random characters from all filter rules up to complete required characters count.
     *
     * @param random Random instance
     * @param rules  Rules
     * @return Randomly chosen characters
     */
    private List<Character> selectCharactersByMissingLength(Random random, List<Rule> rules, int missingLength) {
        List<Character> availableList = rules.stream()
                .flatMap(rule -> rule.text.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // shuffle available list
        Collections.shuffle(availableList);

        return IntStream.range(0, missingLength)
                .mapToObj(i -> availableList.get(random.nextInt(availableList.size()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private static final String LOWER = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        private static final String UPPER = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";
        private static final String PUNCTUATION = "!@#$%&*+-";

        private final List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<>();

        public Builder digits() {
            return custom(DIGITS, 0);
        }

        public Builder digits(int minimumCount) {
            return custom(DIGITS, minimumCount);
        }

        public Builder lower() {
            return lower(0);
        }

        public Builder lower(int minimumCount) {
            return custom(LOWER, minimumCount);
        }

        public Builder upper() {
            return upper(0);
        }

        public Builder upper(int minimumCount) {
            return custom(UPPER, minimumCount);
        }

        public Builder punctuation() {
            return punctuation(0);
        }

        public Builder punctuation(int minimumCount) {
            return custom(PUNCTUATION, minimumCount);
        }

        public Builder custom(String text) {
            return custom(text, 0);
        }

        public Builder custom(String text, int minimumCount) {
            rules.add(new Rule(text, minimumCount));
            return this;
        }

        public PasswordGenerator build() {
            return new PasswordGenerator(this);
        }

        public String generate(int length) {
            return build().generate(length);
        }
    }

    private static class Rule {
        private final String text;
        private final int minimumCount;

        public Rule(String text, int minimumCount) {
            this.text = text;
            this.minimumCount = minimumCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons text has pretty good alternative for random string generation. Builder is used to construct generator, after this generator is easy to use for generation of needed passwords.

```
 // Generates a 20 code point string, using only the letters a-z
 RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
     .withinRange('a', 'z').build();
 String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);
```

Please see

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple algorithm to generate password of your wish.

```
public static final String upperChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static final String lowerChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static final String numbers = "1234567890";
    public static final String specialChars = "!@#$%^&*()_+{}";

    public static String generatePassword(
            int passwordSize,
            boolean useUpper,
            boolean useLower,
            boolean useNumbers,
            boolean useSpecial
    ) {
        char[] password = new char[passwordSize];
        String charSet = null;
        Random random = new Random();

        if (useUpper) charSet += upperChars;
        if (useLower) charSet += lowerChars;
        if (useNumbers) charSet += numbers;
        if (useSpecial) charSet += specialChars;

        for (int i = 0; i < passwordSize; i++) {
            password[i] = charSet.toCharArray()[random.nextInt(charSet.length() - 1)];
        }
        return String.valueOf(password);
    }
```

**Usage**

```
generatePassword(22, true, true, true, true);
```

This returns a String so this can be used directly without converting.

Answer (score 1):

You can randomly choose numbers, letters and punctuations, having a dimension.
Ansii numbers are from 30 to 39, lowercase letters from 61-7A, ans so on. Use [ansii tables](http://ascii.org.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

### Works Java 8+ (no external libraries)

Here is a sample code (simplified version of [this](https://mkyong.com/java/java-password-generator-example/)):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class PasswordGenerator {

    private static final String CHAR_LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static final String CHAR_UPPERCASE = CHAR_LOWERCASE.toUpperCase();
    private static final String CHAR_DIGIT = "0123456789";
    private static final String CHAR_SPECIAL = "!@#$%^";
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static String generatePassword(int length) {

        // Password will contain at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit, 1 special character
        String password = generateRandomString(CHAR_UPPERCASE, 1) +
                generateRandomString(CHAR_LOWERCASE, 1) +
                generateRandomString(CHAR_DIGIT, 1) +
                generateRandomString(CHAR_SPECIAL, 1) +
                generateRandomString(CHAR_LOWERCASE, length - 4);

        return shuffleString(password);
    }

    private static String generateRandomString(String input, int size) {
        
        if (size < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid size.");
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int index = random.nextInt(input.length());
            result.append(input.charAt(index));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private static String shuffleString(String input) {
        List<String> result = Arrays.asList(input.split(""));
        Collections.shuffle(result);
        return String.join("", result);
    }

}
```

Few sample output:

```
6Py!eckpgf
wc#5ecfOmd
j2nDjbkm#w
V%gxhncb9t
zh%hp6jhHf
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would build up arrays of characters ( `char[] ...` ) that represent the various sets of characters that you will allow, and then in your generator method you choose the appropriate character array, and generate the password from that. The complicated part then becomes creating the character arrays...

```
public String generate(char[] validchars, int len) {
    char[] password = new char[len];
    Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        password[i] = validchars[rand.nextInt(validchars.length)];
    }
    return new String(password);
}
```

Then your problem simply becomes generating char[] arrays that represent the various rules you have, and how to pass that set in to the generate method.

one way to do that is to set up a list of regular expression rules that match the rules you allow, and then to send every character through the rules.... and if they match the rules then add them.....

Consider a function that looks like:

```
public static final char[] getValid(final String regex, final int lastchar) {
    char[] potential = new char[lastchar]; // 32768 is not huge....
    int size = 0;
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    for (int c = 0; c <= lastchar; c++) {
        if (pattern.matcher(String.valueOf((char)c)).matches()) {
            potential[size++] = (char)c;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(potential, size);
}
```

Then, you can get an array of aphabetic characters (lowercase only) with:

```
getValid("[a-z]", Character.MAX_VALUE);
```

Or, a list of all 'word' characters with:

```
getValid("\\w", Character.MAX_VALUE);
```

Then it becomes a case of choosing the regular expression to match your requirements, and 'storing' the array of valid characters to be reused each time. (Don't generate the characters each time you generate a password....)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Java implementation of a Unix "pwgen".
https://github.com/antiso/pwgen-gae
It contains the link to jpwgen library implementation with CLI at Bitbucket and the link to GAE deployed sample.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple program that populates an `ArrayList` with ASCII numbers, and then uses a `SecureRandom` number generator to randomise from them in a `for` loop, in which you can set the number of characters you want.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PassGen {

    private String str;
    private int randInt;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private List<Integer> l;

    public PassGen() {
        this.l = new ArrayList<>();
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();

        buildPassword();
    }

    private void buildPassword() {

        //Add ASCII numbers of characters commonly acceptable in passwords
        for (int i = 33; i < 127; i++) {
            l.add(i);
        }

        //Remove characters /, \, and " as they're not commonly accepted
        l.remove(new Integer(34));
        l.remove(new Integer(47));
        l.remove(new Integer(92));

        /*Randomise over the ASCII numbers and append respective character
          values into a StringBuilder*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            randInt = l.get(new SecureRandom().nextInt(91));
            sb.append((char) randInt);
        }

        str = sb.toString();
    }

    public String generatePassword() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getRandomPassword(int count) {
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        switch (getRandomInteger(0, 4)) {
            case 0:
                password.append((char) getRandomInteger(65, 90));
                break;
            case 1:
                password.append((char) getRandomInteger(97, 122));
                break;
            default:
                password.append(getRandomInteger(0, 9));
                break;
        }
    }
    return password.toString();
}

public static int getRandomInteger(int minimum, int maximum) {
    return ((int) (Math.random() * (maximum - minimum))) + minimum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class PasswordUtils {

    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final int MIN_NUM = 6;
    private static final List<Integer> PASSWORD_TYPE_VALIDATE = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));

    /*
     * 21~126
     * */
    private static final char[][] PASSWORD_BASE = {
            {0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39},
            {0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a,
                    0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53,
                    0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a},
            {0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a,
                    0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73,
                    0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a},
            {0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a,
                    0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f},
            {0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0x40},
            {0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f, 0x60},
            {0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e}
    };

    private static String generated(int length, List<Integer> typeList) {
        // exclude
        typeList.retainAll(PASSWORD_TYPE_VALIDATE);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(typeList)) {
            return "dratsPasswd123";
        }

        if (length < MIN_NUM) {
            length = 16;
        }

        char[] chArr = new char[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < (Math.min(length, typeList.size())); i++) {
            chArr[i] = PASSWORD_BASE[typeList.get(i)][random.nextInt(PASSWORD_BASE[typeList.get(i)].length)];
        }

        for (int i = (Math.min(length, typeList.size())); i < length; i++) {
            int index = typeList.get(random.nextInt(typeList.size()));
            chArr[i] = PASSWORD_BASE[index][random.nextInt(PASSWORD_BASE[index].length)];
        }

        // random
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int r = i + random.nextInt(length - i);
            char temp = chArr[i];
            chArr[i] = chArr[r];
            chArr[r] = temp;
        }
        return new String(chArr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();
        for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            System.out.println(PasswordUtils.generated(128, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))));
        }
        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println(stopWatch.getTotalTimeSeconds());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If external libraries are allowed, you can use [identifier-generator](https://github.com/Chaosfirebolt/identifier-generator). It generates random alphanumeric strings with provided count for each character type. Simplified example:

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IdentifierGenerator<String> generator = new AnyCharacterIdentifierGenerator(9, 3, 4, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(generator.generate());
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
w}X$2Qy36crnw_m2Efl
3<i2k8tu.d_hGo5nqRV
Ju5%jihP0i)0p5at;tJ
```

There are more usage examples in the readme.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am the author of this library.

Answer (score 0):

a Simple Password Generator

```java
public class Password {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Variables
        int len = 10;
        String string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
        String result = "";
        
        // Setting the Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            // Generate Password
            result += string.charAt((int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * string.length() - 1));
        }
        
        // Results
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```