# How to Generate Password with compulsory one special character , one Upper case, one lower case In JAVA?

Tags: java

Suppose I am taking input parameter as `int` and I want to return in String. How can I do this? I want compulsory one special character, one upper case, one lower case every time after generating password. How can I do this?

I wrote this code below and I get a solution but it does not add upper case, lower case, special characters in the generated output every time.

```
public int GeneratePassword(int length) {
    String characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstu vwxyz0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?";

    String pwd = RandomStringUtils.random(length , characters );
    System.out.println("pwd:="+pwd );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's RandomStringUtils?

Comment: Looks like you have just copy and pasted the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31260788/6895166

Comment: @Rab https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: i use this lib .

Comment: Either keep your current code but verify the generated string matches your criteria and re-generate it until it does, or randomly decide how many special / upper / lower / digits you will have and where they will be in the string then generate the string by picking characters of the specific symbols

Answer (score 0):

Jose Martinez has provided an excellent method to do achieve already this is a code snippet from his method

```
   public static String getPassword(int length) {
        assert length >= 4;
        char[] password = new char[length];

        //get the requirements out of the way
        password[0] = LOWERCASE[rand.nextInt(LOWERCASE.length)];
        password[1] = UPPERCASE[rand.nextInt(UPPERCASE.length)];
        password[2] = NUMBERS[rand.nextInt(NUMBERS.length)];
        password[3] = SYMBOLS[rand.nextInt(SYMBOLS.length)];

        //populate rest of the password with random chars
        for (int i = 4; i < length; i++) {
            password[i] = ALL_CHARS[rand.nextInt(ALL_CHARS.length)];
        }

        //shuffle it up
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
            int randomPosition = rand.nextInt(password.length);
            char temp = password[i];
            password[i] = password[randomPosition];
            password[randomPosition] = temp;
        }

        return new String(password);
    }
```

if you want to check out the whole method surely check out his answer all credits to him.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51823845/6895166

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `SecureRandom` and `StringBuilder`

```
private static String generateRandomString(int length)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    String uppercaseChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String lowercaseChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String specialChars = "0123456789~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\\\|;:\\'\\\",<.>/?";

    boolean nextIsUppercase = false;
    boolean nextIsLowercase = false;
    boolean nextIsSpecial = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (nextIsSpecial) {
            sb.append(specialChars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(specialChars.length())));
            nextIsUppercase = true;
            nextIsSpecial = false;
            continue;
        }

        if (nextIsUppercase) {
            sb.append(uppercaseChars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(uppercaseChars.length())));
            nextIsUppercase = false;
            nextIsLowercase = true;
            continue;
        }

        if (nextIsLowercase) {
            sb.append(lowercaseChars.charAt(rnd.nextInt(lowercaseChars.length())));
            nextIsLowercase = false;
            nextIsSpecial = true;
            continue;
        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Sample output:

```
System.out.println(generateRandomString(1)); -> 7
System.out.println(generateRandomString(2)); -> :Q
System.out.println(generateRandomString(3)); -> 8St
System.out.println(generateRandomString(4)); -> =Lv%
System.out.println(generateRandomString(16)); ->  %Uf-Hs<Ea|Wp;Rt}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of your problem:

```
public static String GeneratePassword(int length) {

    String[] characters = {"0123456789","~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}|;:\'\",<.>/?","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    Random rand = new Random();
    String password="";
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            int random = rand.nextInt(4);//choose a number from 0 to 3(inclusive)
            int string_size = characters[random].length();//get length of the selected string
            int random1 = rand.nextInt(string_size);//choose a number from0 to length-1 of selected string
            char item = characters[random].charAt(random1);//selects the character
            password=password+item;//Concatenates with the password
        }
    return password;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. This outputs for example wt# or 5'6K which is not what was asked for.

Comment: How the output should look like?