# java - Writing a password generator

Tags: java, passwords

I am trying to code a password generator in Java, and I know exactly the way in which I want to accomplish this. The problem I have is that I am unsure how I can achieve my desired goal.

I want to use a for loop to search through a string, grab a random character, and store that character in the program's memory. I then want to repeat this procedure until the string contains the number of characters specified by the user, and print the resulting string to the terminal.

How can I do this in a way that is simple and straightforward?

Attempt 1:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Write a description of class PasswordGenerator here.
 *
 * @author C.G.Stewart
 * @version 06/06/18
 */
public class PasswordGenerator
{
    private String input;
    private int i;
    private String newPass;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Password
     */
    public PasswordGenerator()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        ArrayList<String> Password = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner pass = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * This method generates a random alphanumeric string to be used as the new 
     * password
     */
    public void generatePassword()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(i=1; i<=20; i++)
        {
            Math.random();
            System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
        }
        //newPass = System.out.println(input.charAt(i));
    }

    /**
     * This method takes the previously generated random alphanumeric string,
     * and outputs it to the screen. 
     */
    public void newPassword()
    {
        System.out.println(newPass);
    }
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * Write a description of class Password here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Password
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String index;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Password
     */
    public Password()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        index="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        Scanner pass = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    //Returns a random alphanumeric string of an inputted length
    public void printPassword()
    {
        for(int i=10; i<=20; i++)
        {
            while(i<=20)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                char letter;

                letter = index.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Random.ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java password generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743124/java-password-generator)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried to solve this, but the only output I get is not at all random, and not remotely what I want. The only code I have is code that is severely broken, and therefore none of it is relevant. So I was asking if anyone had had this problem before, and how they approached it.

Comment: I see no effort to solve it in your post. If it's not in the post, it doesn't exist. *Teacher, I swear I did my homework, but the dog ate it!*

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do it, here are some of them:

**Possibility 1:**

```
public class PasswordGenerator {

       private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        /** different dictionaries used */
        private static final String ALPHA_CAPS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        private static final String ALPHA = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        private static final String NUMERIC = "0123456789";
        private static final String SPECIAL_CHARS = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/";

        /**
         * Method will generate random string based on the parameters
         * 
         * @param len
         *            the length of the random string
         * @param dic
         *            the dictionary used to generate the password
         * @return the random password
         */
        public static String generatePassword(int len, String dic) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            int index = random.nextInt(dic.length());
            result += dic.charAt(index);
        }
        return result;
        }
```

Taken from: [How to generate a random password in Java](https://www.admfactory.com/how-to-generate-a-random-password-in-java/)

**Possibility 2:** [Random.ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-)

**Possibility 3:**

```
public final class RandomStringGenerator extends Object


 // Generates a 20 code point string, using only the letters a-z
 RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
     .withinRange('a', 'z').build();
 String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);

 // Using Apache Commons RNG for randomness
 UniformRandomProvider rng = RandomSource.create(...);
 // Generates a 20 code point string, using only the letters a-z
 RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
     .withinRange('a', 'z')
     .usingRandom(rng::nextInt) // uses Java 8 syntax
     .build();
 String randomLetters = generator.generate(20);
```

Taken from: [Class RandomStringGenerator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.html)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the info, added the code to the links!

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you need to use a for loop to search through the string if you just want to grab a random character from the string?

why don't you just generate a random integer and use it as the index of the string?

something like this:

```
String str, password = ""; 

for (int i=0; i<passwordLength; i++){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(str.length());
    password += str.charAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to the other answers:

Slow:

- do not use `string += "something"` in a loop, use a StringBuilder

Unsecure:

- do not use `Random`, use `SecureRandom`

Code:

```
private static final String ALPHA_CAPS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static final String ALPHA = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static final String NUMERIC = "0123456789";
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARS = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/";

private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
private static final char[] dic = (ALPHA_CAPS + ALPHA + NUMERIC + SPECIAL_CHARS).toCharArray();

public static String generatePassword(int len) { 

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(dic[random.nextInt(dic.length)]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```